# pyvenv installs wrong pip version

Tags: python, pip, archlinux

I'm creating a virtualenv with `pyvenv env` but the installed pip version is outdated. I can manually update pip in the virtual env but I would like to have the correct version automatically.

Without venv activated:

```
~> pip -V
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

Installing the venv:

```
~> pyvenv env
~> source env/bin/activate.fish
```

With venv activated:

```
~> pip -V
pip 6.0.8 from /home/syntonym/test/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

I'm using arch and have pip managed by both, pip and pacman (the arch packet manager), which is probably not a good idea. I still have no idea from where pyvenv gets a 6.0.8 version of pip or how to fix it. Reinstalling with pacman did not help.

EDIT:

ensurepip claims it's already up to date:

```
~> python -m ensurepip --upgrade
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upgrade pip in a virtual environment manually by executing

```
pip install -U pip
```

You are facing this problem, because `venv` uses [ensurepip](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ensurepip.html#module-ensurepip) to add `pip` into new environments:

> Unless the --without-pip option is given, ensurepip will be invoked to
>   bootstrap pip into the virtual environment.

Ensurepip package won't download from the internet or grab files from anywhere else, because all required components are already included into the package. Doing so would add security flaws and is thus unsupported.

Ensurepip is not designed to give you the newest `pip`, but just "a" `pip`. To get the newest one use the manual way at the beginning of this post.

Comment: Manually updating pip in a venv works. ensurepip claims it's already up-to-date (see edit). Or does the `ignoring indexes` indicate some kind of error? I'm not finding that much information on what that means.

Comment: @syntonym my bad, I misread your question. Well, there is no easy way to upgrade pip without upgrading its components bundled with ensurepip.

Comment: If I read your answer correctly, you did understand my question correctly. pip is up to date just as ensurepip (if I read the output of ensurepip correclty). But if I create a virtualenv via pyvenv the pip version is 6.0.8, which is outdated. I'd like that pip in the venv is the up to date pip (7.1.2) without manually updating pip in the venv. Your answer to update ensurepip sounded good, but.. it didn't work.

Comment: @syntonym I am sure, that you get old versions of pip in your virtual environments because of ensurepip. However I am not aware of good methods to upgrade pip inside that package.

Comment: @syntonym to check this you can type into python console `import ensurepip   print(ensurepip.version())`

Comment: You are right! `ensurepip.version()` gives 6.0.8. `python -m ensurepip --upgrade` does indeed upgrade the **pip version in the system** (if it is lower than the version in ensurepip). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @syntonym you can try to upgrade ensurepip manually using files [from this recent commit in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/f649e9c44631c07e707842c42747b651b986dcc4)